# não apagar a imagem no canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

olá, bom dia. Tenho uma imagem fixa no canvas e alguns botões para desenhar ou apagar o que foi desenhado, porém estou com um problema: quando vou usar o botão de apagar ele apaga tudo (inclusive a imagem) e eu gostaria de apagar apenas o que foi desenhado. Isso é possível?

Vou deixar o código abaixo (não sei como fazer para os botões aparecerem pra vcs, mas se for possível pelo menos me dar uma luz do que fazer com base no que foi mandado eu agradeço)

```js
$(function() {
 
 var c = document.getElementById("desenho");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 var img=new Image();
 img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
 img.src="https://app.tisaude.com/c/fichas/1873_fisioterapia.png ";
 img.onload=function()
 {
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,730,350);
 }
    $('#desenho').sketch();
 
 $( "#enviaprontuario" ).click(function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("desenho");
  var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
  $( "#{$q23_id}" ).val(dataURL);
  $("#sProntuario").submit()
 });
 
 
 
  });
  
  var __slice = Array.prototype.slice;
(function($) {
  var Sketch;
  $.fn.sketch = function() {
    var args, key, sketch;
    key = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
    if (this.length > 1) {
      $.error('Sketch.js can only be called on one element at a time.');
    }
    sketch = this.data('sketch');
    if (typeof key === 'string' && sketch) {
      if (sketch[key]) {
        if (typeof sketch[key] === 'function') {
          return sketch[key].apply(sketch, args);
        } else if (args.length === 0) {
          return sketch[key];
        } else if (args.length === 1) {
          return sketch[key] = args[0];
        }
      } else {
        return $.error('Sketch.js did not recognize the given command.');
      }
    } else if (sketch) {
      return sketch;
    } else {
      this.data('sketch', new Sketch(this.get(0), key));
      return this;
    }
  };
  Sketch = (function() {
    function Sketch(el, opts) {
      this.el = el;
      this.canvas = $(el);
      this.context = el.getContext('2d');
      this.options = $.extend({
        toolLinks: true,
        defaultTool: 'marker',
        defaultColor: '#000000',
        defaultSize: 5
      }, opts);
      this.painting = false;
      this.color = this.options.defaultColor;
      this.size = this.options.defaultSize;
      this.tool = this.options.defaultTool;
      this.actions = [];
      this.action = [];
      this.canvas.bind('click mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave mouseout touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel', this.onEvent);
      if (this.options.toolLinks) {
        $('body').delegate("a[href=\"#" + (this.canvas.attr('id')) + "\"]", 'click', function(e) {
          var $canvas, $this, key, sketch, _i, _len, _ref;
          $this = $(this);
          $canvas = $($this.attr('href'));
          sketch = $canvas.data('sketch');
          _ref = ['color', 'size', 'tool'];
          for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            key = _ref[_i];
            if ($this.attr("data-" + key)) {
              sketch.set(key, $(this).attr("data-" + key));
            }
          }
          if ($(this).attr('data-download')) {
            sketch.download($(this).attr('data-download'));
          }
          return false;
        });
      }
    }
    Sketch.prototype.download = function(format) {
      var mime;
      format || (format = "png");
      if (format === "jpg") {
        format = "jpeg";
      }
      mime = "image/" + format;
      return window.open(this.el.toDataURL(mime));
    };
    Sketch.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
      this[key] = value;
      return this.canvas.trigger("sketch.change" + key, value);
    };
    Sketch.prototype.startPainting = function() {
      this.painting = true;
      return this.action = {
        tool: this.tool,
        color: this.color,
        size: parseFloat(this.size),
        events: []
      };
    };
    Sketch.prototype.stopPainting = function() {
      if (this.action) {
        this.actions.push(this.action);
      }
      this.painting = false;
      this.action = null;
      return this.redraw();
    };
    Sketch.prototype.onEvent = function(e) {
      if (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.targetTouches) {
  if (e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0] !== undefined && e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX!==undefined){
   e.pageX = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageX;
  }
  if (e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0] !== undefined &&e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY){
   e.pageY = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].pageY;
  }
      }
      $.sketch.tools[$(this).data('sketch').tool].onEvent.call($(this).data('sketch'), e);
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    };
    Sketch.prototype.redraw = function() {
      var sketch;
      //this.el.width = this.canvas.width();
      this.context = this.el.getContext('2d');
      sketch = this;
      $.each(this.actions, function() {
        if (this.tool) {
          return $.sketch.tools[this.tool].draw.call(sketch, this);
        }
      });
      if (this.painting && this.action) {
        return $.sketch.tools[this.action.tool].draw.call(sketch, this.action);
      }
    };
    return Sketch;
  })();
  $.sketch = {
    tools: {}
  };
  $.sketch.tools.marker = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
      switch (e.type) {
        case 'mousedown':
        case 'touchstart':
          this.startPainting();
          break;
        case 'mouseup':
        case 'mouseout':
        case 'mouseleave':
        case 'touchend':
        case 'touchcancel':
          this.stopPainting();
      }
      if (this.painting) {
        this.action.events.push({
          x: e.pageX - this.canvas.offset().left,
          y: e.pageY - this.canvas.offset().top,
          event: e.type
        });
        return this.redraw();
      }
    },
    draw: function(action) {
      var event, previous, _i, _len, _ref;
      this.context.lineJoin = "round";
      this.context.lineCap = "round";
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.moveTo(action.events[0].x, action.events[0].y);
      _ref = action.events;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        event = _ref[_i];
        this.context.lineTo(event.x, event.y);
        previous = event;
      }
      this.context.strokeStyle = action.color;
      this.context.lineWidth = action.size;
      return this.context.stroke();
    }
  };
  //aqui é onde apaga o que foi desenhado
  return $.sketch.tools.eraser = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
      return $.sketch.tools.marker.onEvent.call(this, e);
    },
    draw: function(action) {
      var oldcomposite;
      oldcomposite = this.context.globalCompositeOperation;
      this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
      action.color = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
      $.sketch.tools.marker.draw.call(this, action);
      return this.context.globalCompositeOperation = oldcomposite;
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12" id="divdesenho"><br>
<br>
   <div class="tools">
   <a href='#desenho' data-color='#000' class="btn" style="background-color: #000"><i class="fa fa-dashboard" style="color: #fff;"></i></a>
   <a href='#desenho' data-color='#CC3300' class="btn" style="background-color: #CC3300"><i class="fa fa-dashboard" style="color: #fff;"></i></a>
   <a href='#desenho' data-color='#2C7227' class="btn" style="background-color: #2C7227"><i class="fa fa-dashboard" style="color: #fff;"></i></a>
   <a href='#desenho' data-color='#6633FF' class="btn" style="background-color: #6633FF"><i class="fa fa-dashboard" style="color: #fff;"></i></a>
   <a href='#desenho' data-color='#9900CC' class="btn" style="background-color: #9900CC"><i class="fa fa-dashboard" style="color: #fff;"></i></a>
    
   <a href='#desenho' data-tool="marker" class="btn" style="background-color: #CCCCCC"><i class="icon-pencil-3" ></i></a>
   <a href='#desenho' data-tool="eraser" class="btn" style="background-color: #CCCCCC"><i class="fa fa-eraser" ></i></a>
 </div>
 <br />
   <canvas crossOrigin="anonymous" id="desenho" width="730" height="350" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;"></canvas>
   <input name="{$q23_name}" id="{$q23_id}" type="hidden">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

o modo "destination-out" tem o efeito pretendido.

```
draw: function(action) {
      var event, previous, _i, _len, _ref;
      this.context.lineJoin = "round";
      this.context.lineCap = "round";
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.moveTo(action.events[0].x, action.events[0].y);
      _ref = action.events;
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        event = _ref[_i];
        this.context.lineTo(event.x, event.y);
        previous = event;
      }
      this.context.strokeStyle = action.color;
      this.context.lineWidth = action.size;
      if (action.tool == "eraser") {
        this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
      }
      else {
        this.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      }
      return this.context.stroke();
    }
  };
  //aqui é onde apaga o que foi desenhado
  return $.sketch.tools.eraser = {
    onEvent: function(e) {
      return $.sketch.tools.marker.onEvent.call(this, e);
    },
    draw: function(action) {
      action.color = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
      return $.sketch.tools.marker.draw.call(this, action);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```